# insulating an exterior rowhouse wall with windows

Tags: insulation

New owners of a row home going through it one room at a time...  We decided to tackle the master/front facing bedroom first.  It has wood paneling (70/80ish) and I am pretty sure the walls behind are plaster on brick on the exterior wall.  thinking to either do foam panels or put up studs and batting - then drywall on top of either one.  This is what I am looking to do on the exterior/façade wall, but I am concerned about the two window.... Since I am adding a few inches to the wall the windows will be a few inches deeper.  Do I need to reinstall the windows within a deeper frame?

Comment: I don't know enough about brick construction, but I would expect you can just replace the interior trim to cover the gap.

Comment: would replacing the interior trim require reinstalling the windows?

Comment: Again, I don't know enough about brick construction, but in wood this would normally not require any change to the windows themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar project.  Generally, when the wall thickness is greater than the window frame, you install  boards as a box to "thicken" the install.  That is, you don't have to touch the window proper, but replace the case.  It's a bit easier to visualize after you've done your demo.

The quick and dirty solution in an image:
[image]

- You'll want 2x framing on all 4 sides.
- Width of the 1x material should be flush-ish with the drywall to be installed later.
- Be very careful with the drilling!.
- The last step before painting and caulking will be to install mitred moulding to cover the exposed edge of the box and the drywall gap.

  - The final step will be to put an attractive potted plant or cat on the sill.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing the age of the home, most row homes have the windows set directly to the brick. You can add framing to carry the new/salvaged trim around the windows. After the insulation is set a "jamb extension' is added to the interior edge of the window to increase the depth of the window on the interior side. Add a picture of what you have and I or others can elaborate more.